# I just flagged a post twice!

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags

Is it just me, or did I just flag a post as both Offensive and as Not an Answer?

Is that a bug (as I thought this wasn't possible before), or <strike>was I just being too awesome</strike> is it by design?

Comment: ah, figured it out - replaced answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Offensive" (a flag/vote) is handled separately to "Not an answer" - so this has always been possible. The hint in the UI is subtle:

[image: needs moderator attention]

Basically, "not an answer" is implemented as a pre-populated ♦ moderator message. This means that yes: you can indeed do both (one flag/vote, and one moderator message).