# I've just flagged the same post twice?

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags

This [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94298/165097) has the exact same title. This time however, it's specialler.

The previous question has had the user flag the same post under different reasons, but I've done it under the same reason "not an answer." Unless it's just me, and that I've misunderstood the answer to the other question.

What's happened? I don't think this is a bug. I have a feeling, it's actually quite legal.

Comment: On which site did you flag?

Comment: EL&U... Does it matter?

Comment: It does if you expect somebody to be able to understand what happened...

Comment: Nah, I mean, does it really matter which site you chose to flag on?

Comment: You misunderstand me... I need to see *data*; you are active on a number of SE sites. I assume this is the one you flagged about 1 hour ago and 9 hours ago?

Comment: Yep. Can you actually see my flag history?

Comment: since I'm part of the SE developer team, yes. For exactly this type of scenario. Understanding a support request often involves understanding the data.

Answer (score 14):

Up until 4 weeks ago, it was indeed the case that you couldn't do this. *Technically* the flag in question was a "moderator message" (albeit with a pre-scripted text), and the logic *used* to be "has the user already added a moderator message for this post? (if so, reject)"; this was recently changed to "has the user got an *open* moderator message for this post? (if so, reject)" - presumably (I'll check) to allow some level of follow-up flagging. In your case, the first flag *had been processed*, hence why you could re-flag.

However, flagging with **the exact same reason** seems undesirable, even if it was processed. I have therefore added a check to reject duplicate flags. This retains the ability to flag the post for another reason / purpose.

Comment: This, sounds very fair.